# Robot framework does not pick up new tests from directory

Tags: robotframework

I have a number of robot scripts in a directory. All the existing ones are fine. However, when I add a new test to to the directory, the newly created tests are not being picked up by the framework. It is a Linux machine. 
However, if I put the same test in the corresponding directory in windows machine, the tests are picked up.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Could you show us the command you are using to run all of the tests in the given Linux / Windows dir?

Comment: If by tests you mean suite files, check their file system permissions - the user that starts the robot execution must have read writes on them, to be able to open the file.

Comment: `<taskdef name="robotant"  
        classname="org.lcx.robotframework.ant.RobotAnt"  
        classpath="${robotant}">  
  </taskdef>  
  
  
 <target name="Test">  
        <robotant  
                jar="${robotjar}"  
                data_sources="${robot.test.dir}"  
                loglevel="INFO"  
                debugfile="jybot.log"  
                outputdir="${robot.result.dir}"  
                maxmemory="512m"  
                fork="true">  
        </robotant>    
  
  </target>  
.  
  <target name="buildtest" depends="clean,Test" />`

Comment: The files have read permissions for all.